# Javac Compiles Program, but Can't Run with Java

Tags: java

I've never had issues with compiling with javac and running with java before, but here we are.

The program, MainApp.java, depends on a jar file and a few other programs, so I ran the following (which ran without issue):

```
javac -cp gson.jar *.java
```

However, when it comes time to run it, I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried:

```
java -cp gson.jar MainApp.java
```

but it complains that it can't find the other java files.
I then tried listing the file it said it was missing:

```
java -cp gson.jar RepositoryData.java MainApp.java
```

but it gave the same error.
I then tried listing all the dependencies:

```
java -cp gson.jar Comment.java Issue.java Owner.java Repository.java RepositoryData.java MainApp.java
```

but it complains that it can't find a main function in the Comment.java file - this leads me to think I'm going about this the wrong way, and I probably shouldn't be directly referencing dependencies in the java call.

I also know that the program *does* work, as I've compiled it using an editor without issue, but I'm required to do this via the command line for a class.

How should I be properly calling it?

Comment: Running without compiling only works for single-file programs.

Comment: I thought javac compiles? Does it do something else entirely?

Comment: are you using any IDE

Comment: Yes `javac` compiles.  That's not the issue.   The issue is your `java`  command line.  Try this: `java -cp .:gson.jar MainApp`.  And then read the manual entry carefully.

Comment: My guess is that you also need to read abou Java packages and how to use them.

Comment: @Stephen C It returns the error "could not find or load main class MainApp", even though the MainApp class file exists. Where would you suggest I start reading about packages?

Comment: @ArshCoder I used IntelliJ to compile it before, and I didn't suffer any issues there.

Comment: 1) Are your classes (e.g. `MainApp.class`) in the current directory.  2) Any good Java tutorial or textbook.  Try the Oracle Java tutorial.  3) Yes.  An IDE (e.g. Intellij) takes care of the classpath for you.  But when you run `java` and `javac` from the command line you need to get the classpath right *for yourself*.  Did you read the explanation of the classpath in the manual entry?  Try this ... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: Are you using MS Windows?

Comment: @StephenC Yeah, I'm using windows 10 (JDK 17). All the files (.jar + .class) are in the working directory, so that shouldn't be an issue. I tried backing out of the directory and executing from above, but that gave the same "could not find or load MainApp" error. I looked through the link you sent, and it says "When classes are stored in an archive file (a zip or JAR file) the class path entry is the path to and including the zip or JAR file." (Third section to bottom), so it seems like it should automatically latch onto the directory the jar file's in, but that doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: @StephenC I've also tried specifying multiple locations by separating them with semi-colons (.:/folder/gson.jar;/folder/), but same error.

Comment: The separator to use on Windows is `;`.  In your last comment you are using `:` at one place and `;` at another.  Have you read the page on the classpath yet?

Comment: @StephenC I've read it over a few times at this point, but I'm still pretty lost. I've tried replacing the : with ; at the beginning, too, but still no change. I went back and retried your first suggestion with a semicolon, (java -cp .;gson.jar MainApp), but it still couldn't find the file till I added .java (and then it still said it couldn't find the dependencies.) I then tried "java MainApp", and it couldn't find it, but sure enough, "java MainApp.java" found it, but lacked dependencies. Is there some reason that adding .java enables the file to be found?

Comment: Erm ... is there a `MainApp.class` file in the current directory?  And the `.class` files for the other Java classes in your project?  Note: when people talk about "dependencies" they don't normally mean other classes in your project.  What they are referring to is class in other libraries (e.g. JAR files) that your classes depend on.  Note that the "." on the classpath means "the current directory".

Comment: The meaning of `java ... SomeClass.java` has already been explained to you. It means "compile and run SomeClass.java".  But it only works when you have **precisely one class** to compile and run.  In your case you have multiple .java files.  So you need to compile them all first using `javac`.

Comment: @StevenC Yeah, after running javac, there's a .class file for each .java file. I didn't realize dependencies specifically meant .jar files, so, to reword it correctly: the error I got in my last comment specified that the program couldn't find RepositoryData.java - and, when I added in RepositoryData.java, it couldn't Repository.java - and so on and so forth till I added all the required files into the java command. However, upon doing that, it complained that the last file I added (Owner.java) didn't have a main function.

Comment: You need to edit your question and show the exact command you are running and the exact output.